# importing csv files into database

Tags: php, csv, import, mysqlimport

here is my code to import csv data to my database

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$c = 0;
**while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $name = $filesop[0];
     $email = $filesop[1];           
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO selleruser (emaili) VALUES ('$name')");
    $c = $c + 1;
    }**     
    if ($sql) {
        echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
    }
   }?>

</div>
```

I have a csv file where there is a column which contains emails

the import is done suvcessfull but the issue is that it just imports the value in another format like in other language or encripted or something un readable

Comment: Is the file you're working with really a csv file? What does it look like in a text editor? What charset is it using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to import csv from phpmyadmin or any other mysql client

Before firing query, please make sure that table matching the fields is already created into db.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'local machine path to csv file' INTO TABLE `selleruser`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(emaili);
```